# Weird Unwanted Bar Appears Along Left and Top of Site

Tags: html, css

I am designing a website for my sister for Christmas, and while building the homepage, ([vhawley.com](http://vhawley.com)), I keep seeing this annoying border pop up along the left and top. Its pretty thin, but it drives me nuts! I have looked all over for and answer and still have not found anything. I have set the site to margin:0 auto, but that just centers it, except for the stupid line.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<title>Victoria Hawley</title>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 1378px)" href="grid-1378.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 1218px) and (max-width: 1377px)" href="grid-1218.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 978px) and (max-width: 1217px)" href="grid-978.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 748px) and (max-width: 977px)" href="grid-748.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 747px)" href="grid-400.css">

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<div id="openImage">
</div>

<div id="nameStrip">
Victoria Hawley
</div>

<div id="largeContainer">
<div id="bigBar">

<div id="middleBar">
<!--Put things for the middle body column here--!>
<h1>About me</h1>

</div>

<div id="leftBar">
<!--Put things for the left body column here--!>
<div id="theatericon">
<img src="images/theatericon.png">
</div>
</div>

</div>

<div id="rightBar">
<!--Put things for the right body column here--!>
</div>

</div>

</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
html{
width:978px;
margin:0 auto;
background:#F0F0F0;
}

#openImage{
float:top;
background-image:url('images/vic-978.jpg');
height:500px;
width:978px;
text-align:center;
}

#nameStrip{
margin:0 auto;
width:978px;
height:130px;
text-align:center;
border-bottom:5px solid #D7D293;
z-index:100;
font-size:100px;
color:#6B00FF;
font-family:cursive,sans;
}

#largeContainer{
height:relative;
min-height:500px;
width:978px;
z-index:1;
position:relative;
}

#leftBar{
float:left;
border-right:5px solid #D7D293;
width:195.6px;
min-height:500px;
z-index:3;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
}

#theatericon{
padding-top:20px;
}

#bigBar{
float:left;
width:778.4px;
position:relative;
}

#middleBar{
float:right;
text-align:center;
min-height:500px;
width:578.8px;
z-index:3;

}

#rightBar{
float:right;
border-left:5px solid #D7D293;
width:195.6px;
min-height:500px;
z-index:3;

}

#404head{
font-size:100;
}
```

Comment: Your question is pretty confusing. It doesnt explain what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Also, please include your code in the question... so we can actually find the problem...

Comment: suddenly a "Weird Unwanted Bat Appears" - you should make this an adventure! - scnr ;)

Comment: If you set the background color of an element like the body to purple, and then you set the background image of the same element, even though the background image fills the element, because of rendering issues, the purple could show through. If this is the case, then you should set the background color of the element to match the average color of the image, or white.

Comment: It's updated with code and "bar", thanks, and as you can see, I already had margin:0;

Comment: Forget it, I figured it out, didn't know you had to have a body tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the `body` element has a margin applied by the browser.

To remove it, add

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

to your style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for html and css debugging.